# Get data from Rest countries API v3 using filter method

Tags: javascript, filter, currency

I was trying to get the currency data from Rest countries API v3.1: https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all. What I was trying to do was get the name of the countries which have United States dollar as it's currency and print it in browser console.

I tried the following code :

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all")
xhr.send();
xhr.onload = () => {
    let data = JSON.parse(xhr.response)
    let answer = data.filter((dummy) => (dummy.currencies !== undefined))
    let realanswer = answer.filter((dollar) => (dollar.currencies.name === "United States dollar"))
    console.log(realanswer)
}
```

But I am getting an empty array in output with no data in it.

I tried to get the data I need with rest countries api v2: https://restcountries.com/v2/all
and got the data I needed with following code:

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://restcountries.com/v2/all")
xhr.send();
xhr.onload = () => {
    let data = JSON.parse(xhr.response)
    let answer = data.filter((dummy) => (dummy.currencies !== undefined))
    let realanswer = answer.filter((dollar) => (dollar.currencies[0].name === "United States dollar"))
    console.log(realanswer)

}
```

So can anyone tell me why I am not getting the data from Rest countries API v3.1? Also I would like to inform that in v2.0 the currency data is stored in an array but in 3.1 it is stored in an object. I can't figure out how to access currencies data with v3.1. Also I want to get the data with the help of filter method only. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

```js
 // Hello Check this out it works absolutely fine
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all")
xhr.send();
xhr.onload = () => {
    let data = JSON.parse(xhr.response)
     /* console.log(data) */
    let answer = data.filter((dummy) => (dummy.currencies !== undefined))
    console.log(answer.length)
    let realanswer = answer.filter((data) =>  {
    for (let key in data.currencies) {
        if(data.currencies[key].name === "United States dollar"){
      return data
      }
    }
    })
    console.log(realanswer.length, realanswer[0].currencies)
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy it works. I did not think of using a for loop inside. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

It's because in v3.1 it's not just `currencies.name`, it's like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answer for [stackzebra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9702500/stackzebra):
Actually you can use this formula:

```
Object.keys(
          data. Currencies
        )[0]
```

for extracting the data from object like this and if there are no other options for currencies you can omit [0]
I hope this solve your problem

Comment: or you can use this :  Object.values(data. Currencies)[0].name

Answer (score 0):

data[0].currencies ? `${ data[0].currencies[Object.keys(data[0].currencies)[0]].name }`: "" ;